# Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:{strictly 1.3} Required by: project :TestApp

Tags: android, gradle

I have error when start connectedDebugAndroidTest gradle task. I performed sync for project, it finished normally, but when I start connectedDebugAndroidTest gradle task the process is failed.

```
>  Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':TestApp:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'
    > Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:{strictly 1.3}
    Required by:
        project :TestApp
        Cannot find a version of 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core' that satisfies the version constraints
            Dependency path 'TestApplication:TestApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3' --> 'junit:junit:4.12' --> 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
            Constraint path 'TestApplication:TestApp:unspecified' --> 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:{strictly 1.3}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3
            Dependency path 'TestApplication:TestApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0' --> 'com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:3.1' --> 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:2.2'
            Dependency path 'TestApplication:TestApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0' --> 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:2.2' --> 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:2.2'
```

My test dependencies are:

```
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0"
```

Android gradle plugin has version 3.4.3 and gradle has version 5.6

P.s. Question was added for "next generation" because I spent 2 days to resolve problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem was is that different versions of hamcrest is required by different libraries. To resolve this, I wrote this code in my :TestApp build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:2.2"
    }
}
```

That code is forces to use only hamcrest library version 2.2